# replace lower case directory with upper case

Tags: .htaccess

How can I use .htaccess to replace all instances of "/test/" in a URL with "/TEST/"?

For example, http://example.com/folder1/test/picture.gif should turn into http://example.com/folder1/TEST/picture.gif

And http://example.com/folder1/test/index.php should turn into http://example.com/folder1/TEST/index.php

Comment: (The mentioned existing question might not directly answer your question, but since you have not presented any actual efforts you made prior to asking, you should go and read up on the basics first.)

Comment: Thanks, I followed the link and ended up at https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/

There I found the following code that did the trick for me:

RedirectMatch 301 /folder1/test/(.*) /folder1/TEST/$1